# Low wifi strength - Fedora 33

Tags: linux, fedora, wifi

I am a regular macOS user, and relatively new to linux distros. Due to my work requirements I decided to install Fedora on my windows PC in dual boot. Anyhow much of the process was smooth and so far I am enjoying fedora except for one thing i.e. I GET WEAK WIFI STRENGTH and POOR SPEED.

I haven't installed any drivers for network myself on the fedora, everything is out of the box. I cant seem to figure out whats causing this issue. Cause sitting at the same spot in my room I get full strength on Windows OS on the very same machine and wifi.

I have a 20MB/s connection and my network controller on this system is

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

Below are some screenshots of fedora and windows showing wifi strength and speed on both OS's:

1. Fedora wifi signal bar
   [image: Fedora wifi signal bar]
2. Fedora speedtest
   [image: Fedora speedtest]
3. Windows wifi signal bar
   [image: Windows wifi signal bar]
4. Windows speedtest
   [image: Windows speedtest]

Answer (score 1):

So finally found a solution to this, don't know exactly whats happening seems like firmware problem but this fixed my issue.

found this solution at

> https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=314231

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/
sudo mv firmware-5.bin firmware-5.bin.orig
sudo mv firmware-6.bin firmware-6.bin.orig
sudo wget "https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/CNSS.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1?raw=true" -O firmware-5.bin

sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
sudo dmesg | grep ath10k
```